# Why does the number of thread remain the same in java application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to learn how multi-threading works in java spring boot application. So I simulated a simple application as this.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PocApplication {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PocApplication.class, args);
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void on() {
        for (int i=0; i <= 50; i++) {
            System.out.println("Start creating a new thread");
            Thread t = new MyCustomThread("test-" + i);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}

class MyCustomThread extends Thread {
    public MyCustomThread(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Running");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And I checked how many threads does the process is using with this command

`jconsole <pid>`

but the number of output remain the same which is 32 threads. So I'm curios why ? and also if springboot by default use embeded tomcat server with the thread pool size 200. why is it only showing 32 instead of 200+ thread?

Comment: And what is `MyCustomThread`? If it does nothing, the thread will exit almost immediately... Thread pools will - depending on the implementation - not allocate all threads in advance, but only if they're actually needed, up to the configured *maximum*.

Answer (score 3):

While it looks like your eventlistener is starting threads it actually doesn't start any threads!

`MyCustomThread` overrides `Thread.start()` and that means that `t.start()` **does not** start a new thread - it just calls `MyCustomThread.start()` (the "magic" of starting a new thread happens because `Thread.start()` internally calls a native method that creates and starts a new thread, not because the method is called "start").

This is one of the reasons why you should **never** (well, almost never) subclass `Thread`.

The following adapted code will create threads that you might be able to see:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PocApplication {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PocApplication.class, args);
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void on() {
        for (int i=0; i <= 50; i++) {
            System.out.println("Start creating a new thread");
            Thread t = new Thread(new MyCustomTask(), "test-" + i);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}

class MyCustomTask implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20_000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I also increased the sleep time - otherwise those threads will all terminate after just one second which might be too short to observe those threads.

Comment: Finally it works Thanks a lot :D